How can I override the search_api server host setting in settings.php?
My server is named "my_server."  When I look at the keys in search_api.server.my_server.yml, I see...
backend_config:
  retrieve_data: false
  highlight_data: false
  site_hash: false
  server_prefix: ''
  domain: generic
  environment: default
  connector: standard
  connector_config:
    scheme: http
    host: example.my.test

So it looks like I should be able to override the host in settings.php with...
$config['search_api.server.my_server']['backend_config']['connector_config']['host'] = 'mytest';

However, this has no effect on the host value displayed at /admin/config/search/search-api/server/my_server/edit
What am I missing?

You are just missing that what you write in settings.php is not reflected in the UI, that's all.

Exactly right.  That possibility didn't cross my mind somehow.
